# Why can Dart not infer or remember the type of my property?

Tags: flutter, dart

After checking if a property of an object in Dart is of a particular subtype, Dart doesn't seem to infer / know / remember that the property `todo` is of that subtype further down in the code.

For example, if I check `state.todo` is of type `Todo_hasChildren` and then later use `state.todo` as a `Todo_hasChildren` type, I get a Dart analysis error ("The argument type 'Todo3' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Todo3_hasChildren'")

I know how to fix this (convert using the `as` keyword or assign the property to its own variable) but why does it not know the type?  Is this temporary in the evolution of Dart or is this something that is permenant?

```
class MyState {
  final Todo todo;

  MyState(this.todo);
}

void doStuff(MyState state) {
  if (state.todo is Todo_hasChildren) //
    processHasChild(state.todo);
}

void processHasChild(Todo_hasChildren todo) {}
```

Comment: Because you have left the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is actually that subclasses of your `MyState` class may override the field with a getter that doesn't consistently give the same value back. Like this:

```
class MyState2 extends MyState {
  MyState2(super.todo);

  @override
  Todo get todo => Random().nextBool() ? Todo_hasChildren() : someOtherTodo();
}
```

Now, when calling `doStuff` with a `MyState2` the type check might pass the first time but when getting it for the `processHasChild` it might return the wrong type.

You can try out this full program to see for yourself that it occasionally crashes because of this:

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
    doStuff(MyState2(Todo()));
}

class Todo{}
class Todo_hasChildren extends Todo{}

class MyState2 extends MyState {
  MyState2(super.todo);
    @override
    Todo get todo => Random().nextBool() ? Todo_hasChildren() : Todo();
}

class MyState {
    final Todo todo;

    MyState(this.todo);
}

void doStuff(MyState state) {
    if (state.todo is Todo_hasChildren) {
        processHasChild(state.todo as Todo_hasChildren);
    }
}

void processHasChild(Todo_hasChildren todo) {}
```

Comment: Great answer.  I was expecting Dart to fix this the last year but of course it is not possible.  Do other languages have this same limitation too?  Or is there actually a way the designers of the language can get around it?  I'm guessing not!

Comment: @atreeon I think many languages don't allow fields to be overwritten like that but I'm not sure

Comment: @atreeon Some other languages chose to favor convenience over safety.  The Dart language team chose safety.  Personally I would have preferred convenience since the scenarios where an override behaves across calls are rare, and in practice developers calling such overrides would end up blindly making explicit unsafe casts anyway.  Also, Dart did *partially* fix it recently (in Dart 3.2) by allowing `final` *private* fields to be type-promoted.  Also see https://dart.dev/tools/non-promotion-reasons

Answer (score 0):

Because `todo` is a property of `state`, and Dart can only infer the type if you promote it from a local variable. This is a very similar case to the [nullable type promotion](https://dart.dev/tools/non-promotion-reasons#other-causes-and-workarounds). See also: [Working with nullable fields](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#working-with-nullable-fields).

So you have to do this instead:

```dart
void doStuff(MyState state) {
  final todo = state.todo;
  if (todo is Todo_hasChildren) //
    processHasChild(todo);
}
```